# I'm trying to make a clear command with role permissions for my Discord bot. (Discord.js)

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have some code already, but how would I implement some other code to make the command only accessible by users with the MANAGE_MESSAGES permission?

My attempt at doing it myself:

```
    else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}clear`)) {
        const amount = parseInt(args[0]);;
        
        if (isNaN(amount)) {
            return message.reply('that doesn\'t seem to be a valid number.');
        } else if (amount <= 0 || amount > 100) {
                return message.reply('you need to input a number between 1 and 100.');
                }
            
        message.channel.bulkDelete(amount, true).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            message.channel.send('Uh oh! Something went wrong!');

        }).catch(() => {
            if (!message.member.hasPermission(['MANAGE_MESSAGES'])) {
                message.reply("you do not have permission to use this command!");
            
            }
        });
    }
```

Without the extra bit at the end:

```
    else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}clear`)) {
        const amount = parseInt(args[0]);;
        
        if (isNaN(amount)) {
            return message.reply('that doesn\'t seem to be a valid number.');
        } else if (amount <= 0 || amount > 100) {
                return message.reply('you need to input a number between 1 and 100.');
                }
            
        message.channel.bulkDelete(amount, true).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            message.channel.send('Uh oh! Something went wrong!');

        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: @Lioness100 No, it's just that everyone without the permissions can use the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}clear`)) {
  // put this at the very top
  if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
    return message.reply("you do not have permission to use this command!");

    const amount = parseInt(args[0]);

    if (isNaN(amount))
      return message.reply("that doesn't seem to be a valid number.");
    if (amount <= 0 || amount > 100)
      return message.reply("you need to input a number between 1 and 100.");

    message.channel
      .bulkDelete(amount, true)
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        message.channel.send("Uh oh! Something went wrong!");
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
}
```

I think the problem is that you were not `return`ing if the member did not have the required permissions, so your code was just continuing on normally.